# Dojo : How to access 'this' from inside a require block?

Tags: dojo

If I'm calling a function from an onclick event, I'd usually use `this` to access the element that fired the event. But if I'm using a dojo require, then `this` is not accessible within the require.

HTML:

```
<button id = "someButton"> Click Me </button>
```

Javascript:

```
require (["dojo/on", "dojo/dom"], function (on, dom) {
    var button = dom.byId ("someButton");
    on (button, "click", doSomething);
});

function doSomething () {
    console.log (this.id); // someButton

    require (["dojo/dom-class"], function (domClass) {
        console.log (this.id); // undefined
        domClass.add (this, "clicked");
    });
}
```

How would I access `this` inside the require?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of approaches to your problem.  The most common solution is to only use a single require for the script block and having all the definitions within the require callback

```
require(['dojo/on','dojo/dom','dojo/dom-class'],function(on,dom,domClass){
    var button = dom.byId ("someButton");
    on (button, "click", doSomething);
    function doSomething (event) {
        console.log (this.id); // someButton
        console.log (this.id);
        domClass.add (this, "clicked");
    });
});
```

Another thing to consider is that the dojo/on module will pass a standardized event object to the event handler.  So in this case `doSomething()` will be passed an `event` object from which you can get the dom  element that was actually clicked.

Comment: Thanks, that worked brilliantly. If I defined a function within a require block like this, would I be able to access it from outside the require block - say in another javascript file?

Answer (score 0):

```
 require (["dojo/dom-class"], dojo.hitch(this,function (domClass) {
        console.log (this.id); // undefined
        domClass.add (this, "clicked");
    }));
```

The function in the require is a callback, so its scope is window when it returns, you can either use bind or dojo.hitch to change the scope.